# Updating Hbase row with Thrift and Hbase.Thrift

Tags: c#, hbase, thrift

I am trying to update a row in Hbase from a MVC site. I am using .NET 4.5 and the best solution I have found to do this is using the Thrift package and Hbase.Thrift to do this.

I have :

```
private static Hbase.Client _hbase; //this is actually a class header
var socket = new TSocket("localhost",9090);
var transport = new TBufferedTransport(socket);
var proto = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
_hbase = new Hbase.Client(proto);

try
        {
            transport.Open();

            _hbase.mutateRows(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Images"), new List<BatchMutation>()
            {
                new BatchMutation()
                {
                    Row = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray(),
                    Mutations = new List<Mutation> {
                        new Mutation{Column = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Image"), IsDelete = false, Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testImage) }
                    }
                }
            });


            transport.Close();
        }
```

While this creates a new image in a given column I have not found a way for it to overwrite and existing column.  Has anyone successfully pulled this off or is there another client tool I should be using to achieve what I am going for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get this setup to work so I went on to use Hbase Rest.  Here is the code for the future lost souls looking for the solution as I was.

```
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hbase_update");
        //check your port number to make sure you have the right one
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:8080/Images/" + key + "?data=");

        request.Method = "PUT";

        //NOTE:The name of the column I am pushing to is int the Column Family "Image" and column "Binary"
        string requestStr =  @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?><CellSet><Row key=""" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)) + @"""><Cell column=""" + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Image:Binary")) + @""">"+ imageBinary + @"</Cell></Row></CellSet>";

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestStr);

        request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        try
            {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(responseString);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```